# How to remove keychain access to visual studio on a mac?

Tags: macos, security, visual-studio-code, keychain, piracy

Three days ago, Visual Studio asked access to my keychain. I thought it was very weird (I have the same  VScode version since two years, downloaded on the official website).

I denied access each time I opened the software, but today, I did a mistake and clicked on "allow access". Is this normal that Vs Code ask such a thing? If not, how to remove access to keychain from VsCode? I have immediately deleted the app from my mac just in case.

Comment: same 
can't find the setting to undo in "Security & Privacy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of your VS Code.
It seems like the keychain access is legitimate.

This is the release note from VS Code (September 2020 (version 1.50)).

VS Code previously accessed the macOS keychain from the window process itself, but now accesses it from the main process. As such, for macOS it prompts for approval like a new application is requesting access, because the process is a different one from before.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_50